# Can't access PhpMyAdmin using MAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I am trying to access phpMyAdmin using localhost/phpmyadmin, I have tried all the ways in StackOverflow such as changing the username, server name, password and it is still giving me this error.

I am using MAMP.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Are you able to connect through the command line client using the same server name, username, and password information? Something like `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`, adjusted for your settings, should get you close.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Hi Isaac! thanks for the reply, I only managed to resolve it by resetting my ports to the default one provided by MAMP, not sure what went wrong tho :( but its working now